# Show that If $W$ is a subspace of $V$, then the restriction to $W$ of the topology Euclidean in $V$ is the Euclidean topology.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, metric-spaces

A topological isomorphism between two topological vector spaces is an application between the two that is both isomorphism and homeomorphism. If $V$ is a vector $\mathbb K$-space of finite dimension $n$ over a field metric $K$, we will call the Euclidean topology in $V$ to the only topology with respect to which all isomorphisms of $V$ in $\mathbb {K}^n$ are topological.

A metric field is a pair $(K, | |)$, where $K$ is a field and $| |$ is an absolute value in K.
An absolute value in K es any function $||:K\rightarrow R$ , where R is an Archimedean ordered body, which fulfills the following properties:

a) $| x | ≥ 0$ and the only element of $K$ that satisfies $| x | = 0$ is $x = 0$.

b) $| x + y | ≤ | x | + |y|$

c) $| xy | = | x || y |$

Show that If $W$ is a subspace of $V$, then the restriction to $W$ of the topology Euclidean in $V$ is the Euclidean topology.

It is shown as follows: "we decompose $V = W ⊕ W'$ and we observe that the identity of $W$ with the Euclidean topology a $W$ with the induced topology is continuous because it is linear and its inverse is continuous because it is the restriction of the projection of $V$ on $W$, which is also linear. Therefore it is a homeomorphism and both topologies coincide. "

I can't understand the demonstration very well, could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show two topologies $\mathcal{T}_1,\mathcal{T}_2$ coincide, one simple way is to show $id:(X,\mathcal{T}_1)\rightarrow (X,\mathcal{T}_2)$ is a homeomorphism.

Now denote the induced topology to be $\mathcal{T}_r,$ the Euclidean topology to be $\mathcal{T}.$ First we prove $id:(W,\mathcal{T})\rightarrow (W,\mathcal{T}_r)\subset (V,\mathcal{T}_V)$ is continuous. This is because it's linear. A fact is that a linear function is countinuous iff it's bounded. While in finite dimension vector space, it's bounded of course.

Then we prove $id^{-1}:(W,\mathcal{T}_r)\rightarrow (W,\mathcal{T})$ is countinuous. While it can be decomposed into
$$(W,\mathcal{T}_r)\hookrightarrow (V,\mathcal{T}_V)\xrightarrow{proj} (W,\mathcal{T})$$
So he says $id^{-1}=proj|_{W},$ which is also linear, and countinuous then.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer, I still have some doubts. I would really appreciate if you could explain me. $\mathcal{T}_V$ is the Euclidean Topology of V? $\mathcal{T}_r$ is the topology induced as subspace of $(V,\mathcal{T}_V)$? why $id$ is continuous ? I thought that the identity function was continuous if and only if  $\mathcal{T}_r\subset \mathcal{T}$

Comment: @OscarFPadilla $\mathcal{T}_V$ is the Euclidean Topology of $V$. $\mathcal{T}_r$ yes. $id$ is continuous because of linearity. $id$ is continuous if and only if $id^{-1}$ maps open set of $\mathcal{T}_r$ to open set of $\mathcal{T},$ so yes, $\mathcal{T}_r\subset \mathcal{T}.$

Comment: @OscarFPadilla About linearity, you can decompose a linear function on basis. And then use your field metric.